# Recursive Embedding & Mongoid - Parent doesn't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm slowly getting crazy with this problem. I'm pretty sure it is something trivial and I have misunderstood something as I am just beginning my journey with Mongoid (and Ruby on Rails).

My model is the following:

```
class Drawing
include Mongoid::Document

    field :image_uid
    image_accessor :image
    field :date_created, type: Time, default: Time.now

    recursively_embeds_many

    embedded_in :user
    embedded_in :painting_template, class_name: 'Painting', inverse_of: :template_drawing
    embedded_in :painting_result, class_name: 'Painting', inverse_of: :result_drawing
```

The User model "embeds_many" Drawings, the Painting model "embeds_one" template_drawing and result_drawing.

What I have been trying to do for the past couple of hours is to create a new Drawing, attach it to a user and define its parent if it has one. I have been playing around in the console a lot but basically what I was doing was similar to this:

```
User.first.drawings.last.parent_drawing = User.first.drawings.first.dup
```

Although the console seems happy and returns the content of User.first.drawings.first, User.first.drawings.last.parent_drawing returns nil...

I have tried to assign them to variables and assign variables etc. But nothing changes. I have tried to create new Drawings and put one as the parent of the other also unsuccessfully.

I came to the conclusion that assigning the parent wouldn't be possible. So I tried to do the other way round and add a child, but I still don't get an object with a parent or a child.

Here's some more code that fails (extracted and shortened from my Rails code):

```
drawing = Drawing.new({:user => @user})
drawing.parent_drawing = @user.drawings.find(parent_id).dup
drawing.save
```

Funnily, the drawing itself is saved and listed in user.drawings, but doesn't have a parent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I gently suggest that the models in your question are too complex if you are just beginning. You have Drawing embedded in Painting via two relations, and also in User, yet you don't have polymorphic: true specified.  You also have recursively_embeds_many.  Do you understand both polymorphism and recursive embedding enough in isolation to take on this much more complex combination as in your question?  I started to look at it, found the tangle of complexity, and kindly request that you simplify your question to the bare minimum if you want to get people to address your question in detail.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I would say I understand polymorphism and recursive embedding as concepts but what I think I'm struggling with is Rails' syntax to express these two concepts. I will definitely try to simplify the models as suggested but during my previous testing with unrelated (and simpler) models the problem remained the same. If you have any thoughts on how to add a parent to a model embedded in itself and itself embedded many times in an other model, it would be mighty useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the advice in the comments I tried to re-think my models from scratch. I reread the doc on polymorphic relationships and made Drawing polymorphic. Still a Drawing should be able to be embedded within another Drawing and recursively embedded led nowhere again.

With the doc/code of Mongoid about cyclic relationships (http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/Cyclic/ClassMethods) I suspected it was because the embeddings "recursively_embeds_many" is doing were wrong because they didn't include the fact that Drawing was polymorphic!

Given that the embedded_in statement is made by the fact that it is polymorphic, adding

```
embeds_one :base_drawing, class_name: "Drawing", as: :drawable, cyclic: true
```

seemed to have the effect I was looking for. It won't include "children" as "recursively_embeds_many" would have done, but it's not necessary in my case.

I hope this helps the next person having trouble with recursively embedded polymorphic relationships.

Comment: Glad that you were able to find the solution, and that you shared it.